# Similar ways to use generators in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm trying to understand the use of yield/generators in python. I would like to know, if given a list of numbers (ex.: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`) the two following statements are equivalent. If they are not, what's the difference?

```
x = (n for n in numbers)
return x


for n in numbers:
    yield n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know they are *almost* equivalent as specified in [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/):

> ```
> g = (x**2 for x in range(10))
> print g.next()
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> def __gen(exp):
>     for x in exp:
>         yield x**2
> g = __gen(iter(range(10)))
> print g.next()
> ```

However it's just *almost* equivalent, the difference *in your case* is **when** `iter(numbers)` is evaluated:

```
>>> def f1(l):
...     x = (n for n in l)
...     return x
... 
>>> def f2(l):
...     for n in l:
...         yield n
...         

>>> a1 = f1(1)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

>>> a2 = f2(2)  # works
>>> next(a2)    # fails only after calling "next"
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

`f1` will immediately try to do `iter(l)` while `f2` will do `iter(l)` only after calling `next` on it.

To be truly equivalent you would need to pass `iter(numbers)` into the function that uses `yield`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there's no significant difference. Both of the notations create a generator, and doesn't execute the statement instantly.